Running test on a local agent ends randomly with : "The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed"
I have a CI/CD set up on Azure DevOps. When I run unit tests on the CI, everything works fine. For some specific hardware needs, I have set up a local agent on a computer to run the same tests, the thing is, as title says, it randomly (i.e. not every run) crashes with the message "The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed" and nothing more, no stack, no exception, nothing. It doesn't even break the test run, it runs more tests after that according to logs.
I'm using the feature "Releases" in ADO "Pipelines". The generated YAML for my test run looks like this :
steps:
- task: VSTest@3
  displayName: 'Tests run'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: '**\*Tests.dll'
    vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
    runInParallel: false
    publishRunAttachments: false
    rerunFailedTests: false
  continueOnError: true

At this point I'd just like some help to add logs to be able to find the issue, thanks in advance.
For an idea about the volume of tests, I have ~1500 tests running as expected in ~20 dlls and two dlls are failing from time to time, always the same.
What I tried so far :

I had a look at the windows logs on the local computer but found nothing.
I ran the very same tests through Visual Studio they all run smoothly multiple times.
I tried to play with the settings in the Pipeline/Release task (parallel or not, isolated or not...), nothing changed.
I ran the tests locally through Powershell using the same generated query (vstest.console.exe [myTests.dll]) and no error either.

Edit to add some logs with context :
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.8.0+6438bb880a (64-bit .NET 8.0.5)
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.09]   Discovering: XXX.Tests
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.12]   Discovered:  XXX.Tests
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.13]   Starting:    XXX.Tests
##[error]The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.8.0+6438bb880a (64-bit .NET 8.0.5)
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.09]   Discovering: YYY.Tests


When you say run the test locally through Powershell and no error, are you running on the failed agent machine(same one)? For the error details, have you checked the worker and agent diagnostic log? Please share some log if there's any finding.

Yes, I'm using the .exe installed by the previous step of the pipeline :
`steps:

task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
displayName: 'Visual Studio Test Platform'
inputs:
versionSelector: latestStable`

I downloaded the logs but they are desesperately unhelpful.

So i understand you are checking on the failed agent machine with vstest.console.exe and it works. Since you are testing based on the tests dll, please try to test half of the tests.dll, and then add the VsTest task again, test the left tests dll. You can specify the dll in the parameter testAssemblyVer2, let's separate the tests for a check.

After several retries I managed to reproduce the failing while executing manually in a powershell (as I said, it is not a consistent error). Not sure what I should do next, there aren't more informations available this way.

I can reproduce by running the same 3 dlls, they are the one failing from time to time and I have a strong idea why since they all rely on the same external module. But still would like to have details about the failing, if you have an idea on how to enable more detailed logs that would help a lot.

Maybe you can try dotnet test --blame to check if there're more details, which could be caused by async void method. Please refer to the similar ticket for the details. In addition, as it can be reproduced on local command, it's recommended to raise a new ticket on link for help.

may i know how is it going? You can share the solution if it's resolved, thanks.

Still got the same issue, happening randomly. I will be sure to share the solution if I ever find one. Currently we settled for the idea that sometime it will fail and we will have to rerun it.

The Test host process crashed could be caused by many reasons,  such as temporary network issue, or not enough CPU, RAM... on the agent. For the task VSTest@3, you can set rerunFailedTests: true to automatically rerun the failed tests(% failure or # of failed tests), please check if it helps.
